# Where and when can I craft bombs?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I'm not very far into Constantinople, but I've already collected a lot of bomb ingredients. However, I don't seem to be able to do anything with them.

I assume at some point I'll be able to make bombs. Do I have to go somewhere to do this? When does the option first become available?

Comment: Is this really a problem? Why don't you go ahead and try? Posting every single place you are not even stuck at does not a question make

Comment: @Bora Sorry if this seems trivial to you. I haven't finished an AC game since the first, and a fair amount of Ezio's skills aren't really explained to the player at the start of this one. I wanted to make sure that bomb-making wasn't already available to me and I was just missing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to wait until **Yusuf** teaches you how to do so.  You learn it in **Sequence 3, Memory 4**, "Bomb Crafting".

To be able to craft the bombs, you need to go to a crafting table.  They look like little wooden cupboards hanging on the side of a wall, often sitting next to a pigeon coop.  The icon is a little white bomb on the map.

I noticed that you can even add more bombs to your inventory from the **Weapon Wheel**.  Provided that you have at least one bomb that you want to recreate (but not at capacity) and you have the ingredients to make it.  Open the weapon wheel, select the bomb you want to create and press <kbd>A</kbd> (or whatever is appropriate for your control scheme) to **Add Bomb**.  It will add more of that bomb to your inventory.

Comment: You'll notice soon enough that they are scattered around the town, so once you can make them, they'll be around when you need one.

Comment: Sticky pouches and trip wire shells are difficult to come by at first, fyi, but everything else is lying around in spades.