# What are the worthwhile rewards from doing the faction challenges?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

Every faction in Assassin's Creed: Revelations appears to have a few sets of challenges associated with them.  Under some of them it appears there is a reward for completing an entire set.  However, I'm having a tough time determining which rewards are actually useful.  For instance, one of the bomb maker challenges gives me bomb ingredients at my hideouts, but I have no idea how many ingredients, how fast they respawn, and if they are "rare" or "common" variants.

Is there a list of the challenge rewards, and approximately how useful they end up being?  I'd rather not farm a bunch of these challenges if they make very little difference to the game.  However, if having one of these rewards early makes certain missions or facets of the game simpler, I'd like to prioritize it.

Comment: If nobody else does, I can put together a list when I get home tonight, but suffice to say: You can completely ignore these without worry.  The only ones that are really all that incredibly useful are the assassin upgrades, which you're likely to get without even trying, and the bomb capacity upgrade.  Most of them are just "unlock an item (which isn't very useful)" or "reduce the cost of hiring NPCs".

Comment: I personally LOVE the theives because they pick everyone's pockets. You end up getting tons of cash that way, as well as an achievement eventually after they loot enough dead guards for you. You kill the guards, they loot their pockets. As for the other factions, I think they're all purposeful. Maybe I'm the only one, but I recommend getting them done as you progess through the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an overview of what each of the challenges provides you if you complete them.  I don't know what is more worthwhile to you so you decide.

#### Assassins Guild:

1. > Assassins will be more effective when sent on missions.

   Sending your assassins on missions in **Mediterranean Defense** gives you a free 9% bonus in the odds of success.  It could be helpful to you if you want to send your assassins out on missions with the least amount possible with guaranteed survival.
2. > Assign Signal recharges at an increased speed.

   Self explanatory.  You can call assassins to help you out more often since the meter will recharge faster.  If you need/want the help, this would be a great challenge to meet.
3. > Unlocks the Assassin Faction weapon.

   Unlocks **Altair's Sword** which is a decent sword with stats 5/3/4. It's not a max stat sword this time, but **Yusuf's Turkish Kijil** is.

#### Mercenaries Guild:

1. > Cost of hiring Mercenaries decreases.

   Reduces the cost of hiring **Mercenaries** from **150** to **75**.  Mostly useless, money is easy to come by.
2. > Unlocks Mercenary Faction ability.

   Hired **Mercenaries** will protect you from any hostile/troublesome civilians.  So if you anger people from pickpocketing them, they're dead.  If beggars come at you, they'll be pushed away.  They'll probably even detract or kill off stalkers you might come by.  Not particularly useful if you asked me.
3. > Unlocks the Mercenary Faction weapon.

   Unlocks the **Broadsword** which is an strong heavy sword with stats 5/4/4. It's not a max stat heavy weapon though, but the **Almogavar Axe** is.

#### Romanies Guild:

1. > Cost of hiring Romanies decreases.

   Reduces the cost of hiring Romanies from 150 to 75.  Mostly useless, money is easy to come by.
2. > Unlocks Romani Faction ability.

   When a hired **Romani** distracts a guard, they will (slow) poison them when you send them to distract or walk by them.  Useful if you want to kill guards with the least amount of trouble.
3. > Unlocks the Romani Faction weapon.

   Unlocks the **Romani Stiletto** which is a decent knife with stats 5/3/4. It's not a max stat knife, but **Mehmet's Dagger** is.

#### Thieves Guild:

1. > Cost of hiring the Thief Faction decreases.

   Reduces the cost of hiring Thieves from 150 to 75.  Mostly useless, money is easy to come by.
2. > Unlocks Thief Faction ability.

   Enables thief stealing.  Thieves you hire will steal from civilians as they pass by them and loot dead guards.  A necessity if you want the **Fast Fingers** achievement.
3. > Unlocks the Thief Faction weapon.

   Unlocks the **Ottoman Mace** which is an decent mace with stats 4/4/2. Not my kind of weapon but it has a decent speed over all the other faction weapons at the cost of some damage and speed. Mostly useless IMHO.

#### Bombs:

1. > Extra bomb ingredients found within Dens.

   It just gives you a little more of the ingredients from the chests in the dens. I've always had full ingredients at all times (even when using bombs somewhat frequently) so I don't know how useful this would be.
2. > Bomb capacity upgrade.

   Allows you to carry an additional bomb per pouch. I don't know how useful this is considering [you can replenish your bombs from the weapon wheel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/39508/8995).

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

- Assassin Challenges

  - Successfully go through Set 3 and you get Altair’s Sword.
- Mercenary Challenges

  - Successfully go through Set 2 and you can get Hired Mercenaries Stop Beggars.
  - Successfully go through Set 3 and you get the Broadsword.
- Romani Challenges

  - Successfully go through Set 2 and you can get Hired Romanies Poison Guards.
  - Successfully go through Set 3 and you get the Romani Stiletto.
- Thief Challenges

  - Successfully go through Set 2 and you get Hired Thieves Pickpocket.
  - Successfully go through Set 3 and you get the Ottoman Mace.

(from a website I forgot but they probably all copy from one to the other :))

As @Shinrai said, almost nothing worth losing hours for this...

Comment: Yikes, yeah, nothing of that is really all that appealing.  I barely use any weapons but the hidden blade anyhow.